# React Native Lottie not executing in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, native, lottie

I have the following problem in terminal after the 'react-native run-ios'.

> The following build commands failed:
>     CompileC Path/MyApp/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/LottieReactNative.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LottieReactNative.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LRNContainerView.o LottieReactNative/LRNContainerView.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
>   An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>   Failed to install the requested application
>   An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I have no idea what might be wrong, any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :) 
'react-native upgrade' in terminal, resolved the problem. But be careful, it overwrites android and iOS config files.